# Receiving 'Premanent Redirect 308' error in Python suds, but not in SoapUI

Tags: python, http, redirect, soap

I'm trying to do webservice calls in Python using suds package, based on SoapUI webservice calls. I could manage to have proper results in SoapUI, but keep getting 'Permanent Redirect 308' error in Python.

The code looks like:

```
from suds.client import Client
client = Client('https://xxx.yy.zz/a/b?wsdl')

#so far this works fine, I can even print the services and types of the client

param1=client.factory.create('Param1')

param1_1=client.factory.create('Param1_1')
param1_1.firstName='John'
param1_1.lastName='Meow'
param1_1.level='&lt;?xml version=1.0 encoding="UTF-8"?&gt;&lt;etc'
param1_1.identification='jmeow'

param1.param1_1=param1_1
param1.ref='5432'

#I tried to use escape for the level inner parameter, but it shouldnt matter, 
#because even if it's wrong, I should still use the call, but no correct response from it

result=client.service.MyService(param1)
```

In SoapUI, I had to turn off proxy settings on the top bar to 'Proxy Setting: None'. Also tried both http and https, it does not work with http in SoapUI either. I do not do any authorization in SoapUI,other than the service parameters as above.

Any idea what do I do wrong?